# CoreData crash while adding new entity with relationship

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a problem using CoreData.

I have the following model:

Entity: Library with a relationship to many Book
Entity: Book with a relationship to one Library

I'm trying to add a Book and when I set its relation to the library, the app crashes.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var library: Library!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    addCheckIt("", author: "")
}

func addCheckIt(title: String, author: String) {
    let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
    let bookDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Book", inManagedObjectContext: context)
    let myBook = Book(entity: bookDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)

    myBook.title = title
    myBook.author = author

    myBook.library = library

    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch let err as NSError {
        print(err.debugDescription)
    }
}

}
```

It crashes at myBook.library = library. Then I get this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSSet intersectsSet:]: set argument is not an NSSet'

I've searched for hours and I can't find out a solution, please help me.

```
extension Library {

    @NSManaged var name: String?
    @NSManaged var books: NSSet?

}

extension Book {

    @NSManaged var author: String?
    @NSManaged var title: String?
    @NSManaged var library: Library?

}
```

Comment: Pablo, it would be a good idea to re-post this question and properly re-upload the screenshots.

Comment: Are you sure you've declared `library` as a one-to-many relationship and not many-to-one or many-to-many?

Comment: delete the app after setting its relationship, clean and then build the project.

Comment: @TamásZahola yes, I've set a one-to-may relationship

Comment: @Himanshu I've just tried this out but it does the same

Comment: @ppablo, variable type Library is not compatible with one that you have in you CoreData Model

Comment: @pedrouan why not?

Comment: @ppablo You should know or to dissent. Place the code where we could see the attribute definition, in your CoreData model class.

Comment: @pedrouan I think it is because I used elsewhere in the project and it works

Comment: I guess you miss something like '@NSManaged var book: Book?' in your 'Library' extension. If I would still stuck, I'd regenerate the class with clicking on .xcdatamodel and choosing from menu Edit -> Create NSManagedObject subclass. This will affect '+CoreDataProperties.swift' files only so you don't have to worry your other data model classes will get lost.

Comment: And check whether both entities in your xcdatamodel have selected destination (to each other) properly within their relationship.

Comment: Refer this github tutorial for [Swift-CoreData-Relationship](https://github.com/DipenPanchasara/Swift-CoreData-Relationship/blob/master/SwiftSample/Model/User.swift)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use a `NSOrderedSet` for the one-to-many relationship.(If you haven't do that).

```
class Library{
    @NSManaged var books: NSOrderedSet
    ...
}
```

your Book class should be

```
class Book{
    @NSManaged var library: Library
    ...
}
```

where **books** and **library** in the `xcdatamodeld` should be the name of the relationships between the models. 
Another thing, the relationships must be inverse in your case.
Finally I suggest you to set:

`library.books.addObject(book)`

but for do this you need to use a **NSMutableOrderedSet** instead a **NSOrderedSet**

**UPDATE**

Try to create Book object as described below:

```
let book: Book = NSManagedObject(entity: bookDescription, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context) as! Book
```

Comment: thanks, I changed and made an ordered set as you suggested but I still get the error